# Find $\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}[f(f(x))-f(x^2)])(3)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

find $\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}[f(f(x))-f(x^2)])(3)$

if $f(3)=3,  \frac{\mathrm{d f} }{\mathrm{d} x}(3)=2,   \frac{\mathrm{d f} }{\mathrm{d} x}(\sqrt{3})=1$ y $\frac{\mathrm{d f} }{\mathrm{d} x}(9)=1$

pls I need a hint

Comment: You can split up the derivative over the sum, so you just need to find $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} f(f(x))$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} f(x^2)$. Both of these can be done with the chain rule.

Comment: Which $x$ are you finding the derivative at?

Comment: @JoshuaWang at x=3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac {d}{dx} [f(f(x)) + f(x^2)] = f'(f(x))f'(x) + 2xf'(x^2)$

Evaluated at 3.

$f'(f(3))f'(3) + 6f'(9)$

Plug in the values you know... $f(3) = 3, f'(3) = 2, f'(9)  = 1$

$2f'(3) + 6$

And again...

$4 + 6 = 10$